# Unable to subtract specific fields within structured numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

While trying to subtract to fields within a structured numpy array, the following error occurs:

```
In [8]: print serPos['pos'] - hisPos['pos']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-8-8a22559cfb2d> in <module>()
----> 1 print serPos['pos'] - hisPos['pos']

TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types 
dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')]) 
dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')]) 
dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
```

Given the standard float dtype, why would I be unable to perform this subtraction?

To reproduce these conditions, the following example code is provided:

```
import numpy as np

raw = np.dtype([('residue', int),
    ('pos', [('x', float),
    ('y', float),
    ('z', float)])])

serPos = np.empty([0,2],dtype=raw)
hisPos = np.empty([0,2],dtype=raw)

serPos = np.append(serPos, np.array([(1,(1,2,3))], dtype=raw))
hisPos = np.append(hisPos, np.array([(1,(1,2,3))], dtype=raw))

print serPos['pos'], hisPos['pos']  # prints fine
print serPos['pos'] - hisPos['pos'] # errors with ufunc error
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dtype` for `serPos['pos']` is compound

```
dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
```

subtraction (and other such operations) has not been defined for compound dtype.  It doesn't work for the `raw` dtype either.

You could subtract the individual fields

```
serPos['pos']['x']-hisPos['pos']['x']
```

I think we can also `view` `serPos['pos']` as a 2d array (3 columns) and subtract that form.  But I need to test the syntax.

```
serPos['pos'].view((float,(3,)))
```

should produce a `(N,3)` 2d array.

Comment: Thank you hpaulj for clarifying this.

I was also able to remedy the issue by changing the `np.dtype` to

`raw = np.dtype([('residue', int),('pos','(1,3)f8')])`

Now `serPos['pos'] - hisPos['pos']` works perfectly.

Cheers!

Comment: I would have used `'(3,)f8'` so `serPos['pos']` is `(N,3)` as opposed to `(N,1,3)`.